# Why is Pydot not installed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pydot

I am working my way through Google's Machine Learning videos. To complete one of the modules, I had to pip install pydot, which was done successfully in the command prompt. I went back to my code, and I keep getting an error-"name 'pydot' is not defined," but I have made sure, multiple times, that I installed it. I even closed jupyter and re-opened it and I get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pydot
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
test_idx = [0, 50, 100]

train_target = np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
train_data = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis=0)

test_target = iris.target[test_idx]
test_data = iris.data[test_idx]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data, train_target)

print(test_target)
print(clf.predict(test_data))

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO

dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf,
                out_file=dot_data,
                feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                class_names=iris.target_names,
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                impurity=False)
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")

print(test_data[0], test_target[0])
```

Comment: The python you use to run your script should be the same python/pip env you used to install pydot.

Comment: That error is not possible with this code.  Please edit the question to be the real code you're using.  Also please include the full error traceback message.

Comment: I found out that pydotplus is the module I should use, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You are maybe using virtual env for your project but installed pydot globally, or maybe you have multiple python versions and you installed pydot on lets say 3.6 but you are running your project on 3.7 But if you are going through a tutorial it's most likely they made you create a virtual env but you didn't quite understood the concept of virtual env. Happens with everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code in the IDLE, it could be that your IDE doesn't recognize the package. If that works, you'll have to import the package in the Project Settings.